# SAML based authentication for SOAP Web Services

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, soap, saml

I am struggling with `SAML` based authentication for `SOAP Web Services` from last couple of days. I have gone through tons of tutorials to understand the concepts and setting up `SAML` authentication in my local environment. However, I am not getting couple of things on it.

I have created and hosted the web services and written consumer to access those services (With Java). I have also set up `OpenAM` to act as `Security Token Service` (STS)/Identity Provider (As described in most of the tutorials).

My understanding on SAML authentication for Web Services are as below:

1. A Web Service consumer should authenticate itself with some means (e.g. credentials) and get a `SAML response token` with certain assertions from a Security Token Service (STS)/Identity Provider (IdP).
2. Service Consumer then present the `SAML` token to the Web Service it is accessing and based on the authentication, web service will decide to access/deny.

I am not able to understand following things:

1. How can I configure `OpenAM` correctly as `STS/IdP`. Most of the tutorials I have seen on `OpenAM` are focused on `Single Sign On (SSO)` and configuring `IdP/SP` for the same. Also many of them are on `LDAP` context.
2. What changes I have to do in service consumer so that it will request for a `SAML` token before accessing the services.
3. How web services will validate the `SAML` token and allow the consumer to access the service.